# How to filter the data from Rdd and save it to text file using scala in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have two datasets which are in TSV format. I want to read both TSV file in spark scala and perform analysis. File 1 has Aug data and File 2 has Sep data.
How do I read both tsv file using scala in spark and save output to another tsv file. I want to use intersection operation on both the RRD

Below are the two TSV file format.
File 1

[image]

File 2

[image]

The output file should have the App_Name which are accessed in both the months.

Output file data.

[image]

Comment: have you at least tried anything?

Comment: I have read the files but not able to perform intersection operation to get desired o/p   val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

val file1 = spark.read.option("sep", "\t").csv("file1path")
val file2 = spark.read.option("sep", "\t").csv("file2path")

Answer (score 0):

```
val dfTsv1 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("delimiter", "\t")
      .load("filepath1")
    val dfTsv2 = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .option("delimiter", "\t").load("filepath2")


    val duplicateColumns = List("") // put your duplicate column names here 
    val outputDf = dfTsv1.alias("tcv1").join(dfTsv2.alias("tcv2"),dfTsv1("ACCESSED_MONTH") === dfTsv1("ACCESSED_MONTH"))
      .drop(duplicateColumns: _*)

    outputDf.show()
```

Comment: @Saurabh If you are using this solution then atleast accept it consider accepting it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61484379/getting-error-as-org-apache-spark-sql-analysisexception-cannot-resolve-column-n

Answer (score 0):

The intersection is nothing but the inner join, simply perform an inner join operation on both the Dataframes. Refer [Spark SQL Joins](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins.html)

```
val df = df1.join(df2, Seq("APP_NAME"), "inner")
```